# Angular 5: Rename/obfuscate CSS selectors

Tags: css, angular

Is there any way to rename/obfuscate CSS selectors in an Angular CLI project? If you look at the HTML of sites like Google or Facebook, you will see randomized CSS names.

I assume this is for many reasons, including and not limited to preventing people from scripting your website by targeting static class names.

I want to do something similar in my app, however I don't see any trivial way to do so. [This article](https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda) shows how to do it with one line using webpack, however Angular CLI doesn't allow any webpack configuration as far as I know.

Is there any solution to this without having to write a custom script, or will I just need to write some kind of custom script? I have no problem doing that, just want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular CLI does in fact allow Webpack configuration.

To eject webpack write:

`$ ng eject`

What this will do is generate a webpack.config.js file for you, which you can edit and customize however you want (add your css rules in it etc...)

But you will not be able to start your project using `ng serve`, you will have to run `npm run build & npm run start` for it to work!

Edit: If you want to undo `ng eject`  you will have to edit your `.angular.cli.json` file and set `ejected` to `false`:

```
"project": { 
  ...
  "ejected": false
}
```

Here's some more info: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6302

Comment: Is `ng eject` reversible? Is it recommended against? Are there any adverse side effects, or is the only different that you have to use `npm` commands instead of `ng`? Got any links for documentation on this? Thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer for you.

Comment: See also: [ng eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject)

Comment: `eject` seems like a poor solution to a common problem, hopefully they will make this better in the future. I just want to configure the build, don't want to have to break future upgrades and support for CLI commands. Nonetheless, it answers my question so thanks.

Comment: ng eject is no longer supported by Angular

Answer (score 0):

You could parse your code after the build with [rename-css-selectors](https://github.com/JPeer264/node-rename-css-selectors)